# C# WPF MVVM - Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, drag-n-drop

Задача, сделать возможность для перетаскивания элемента из ListView в TreeView и обратно.
Получается только перетащить выделенный текст из TextBox в TreeView только как новый узел.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeCollection}" AllowDrop="True">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildTree}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Drop">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DragDropCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewDragOver">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding PreviewDragEnterCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewDragEnter">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding PreviewDragEnterCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TreeView>
```

**ViewModel**

```
DragDropCommand = new Commands.RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    var arg = parameter as System.Windows.DragEventArgs;

    //DoDrag //(?)

    string text = arg.Data.GetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.Text).ToString();

    TreeCollection.Add(new TreeItem() { Text = text }); //Эта коллекция привязана к TreeView
}, parameter => true);

PreviewDragEnterCommand = new Commands.RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    //drgevent.Handled = true; //(?)

    var drgevent = parameter as System.Windows.DragEventArgs;
    if (drgevent.Data.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.DataFormats.Text))
    {
        drgevent.Effects = System.Windows.DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
    else
        drgevent.Effects = System.Windows.DragDropEffects.None;
}, parameter => true);
```

Вопросы:

- Как в данном случае работать с методом DragDrop.DoDragDrop?
- Как перетащить элемент в указанный курсором (при падении) узел?
- Как передавать DragEventArgs через команду "RelayCommand < T > " PassEventArgsToCommand?

Буду благодарен за примеры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует [готовое решение,](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop) совместимое с MVVM.
Рекомендую использовать и не изобретать собственный велосипед. Если очень хочется, подсмотри реализацию и перепиши под себя.

Если же это решение не подходит, то, обычно, используются класс-контроллер, который обрабатывает независимые события и запоминает текущее состояние: перетаскивается данная ViewModel, курсор находится над этой ViewModel и т.д., в результате чего, на момент срабатывания Drop, у тебя есть информация обо всех участниках процесса. Контроллер спускается во все зависимые компоненты, включая команды перетаскивания элементов.

Как говорится:

> MVVM is dead, long live MVVMC!

Comment: " long live MVVMC!"  - а как начнешь искать про него и особенно детали, так только восхищенные статьи "как это круто" и 1.5 реализации причем как их видит реализатор. )